# Showing that $Df^{-1}(f(x)) = Df(x)^{-1}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds, jacobian, diffeomorphism

> Let $V$ and $U$ be open sets in ${\bf{R}}^n.$ Let $f: U\to V$ be a diffeomorphism. Show that $Df(x)$ is bijective for all $x \in U$ and that $Df^{-1}(f(x)) = Df(x)^{-1}.$

The question seems a bit odd. It's a direct result from the Inverse Function Theorem right?

For the first part shouldn't $f$ be a bijection already for it to even be a diffeomorphism?

> ${\displaystyle f\colon M\rightarrow N}$ is called a diffeomorphism if it is a bijection and its inverse ${\displaystyle f^{-1}\colon N\rightarrow M}$ is differentiable as well.

The second part seems to be something I'm not sure on how to approach. We want to show that the derivative of the inverse of $f$ applied to $f(x)$ is the inverse of the derivative? Here $Df$ is an operator (matrix?) so $Df^{-1}$ would just be the derivative of the inverse, but I'm a bit confused on what does the notation $Df(x)^{-1}$ mean? Also from the problem statement we know that $Df$ is invertible since it's a diffeomorphism and $\det(Df)) \ne 0$ right?

Comment: No need for IFT: apply the chain rule to $f^{-1}\circ f = {\rm Id}$.

Comment: I have that since $f$ is bijective $\forall y \in V$ there exists $x \in U$ s.t. $f(x)=y$. Similarly $f^{-1}(y) = x$. Thus $(f^{-1} \circ f)(x) = f^{-1}(f(x)) = f^{-1}(y) = x. \Longrightarrow f^{-1} \circ f = {\rm Id} $ However, I'm not sure how to continue from here? How should I apply the chain rule? @IvoTerek

Comment: Do you know the statement of the chain rule in $\Bbb R^n$? I don't know how to explain without giving you the full solution, there's only *one* step to do. You should not have any issue doing it.

Comment: You mean the one that states something of the following $D(g \circ f) = Dg \circ Df$? Assuming that $f : \mathbb{R^p} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ and $g : \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R^m}$. @IvoTerek

Comment: Yes, exactly that one. Now please try to think a bit harder about it.

Comment: This seems to result in $D(f^{-1} \circ f)(x) = Df^{-1}(f(x)) = Df^{-1}(x) \cdot Df(x)$?

Comment: Not quite. Keep track of base points.